# How to find a Control inside a ListView ItemTemplate in WPF Desktop application?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ListView like this:

```
 <ListView Name="Ppls">
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
             <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                   <ColumnDefinition/>
                   <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Source="path/image.png" Grid.Column="0" Height="150"/>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="10 0">
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                   <TextBlock Text="TEXT"/>
                   <TextBlock Text="TEXT"/>
                   <DockPanel>
                      <DockPanel.Resources>
                         <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource PrimaryButton}">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 5 0"/>
                         </Style>
                      </DockPanel.Resources>
                      <ItemsControl Name="ButtonsList">
                         <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type commons:Boton}">
                               <Button ToolTip="{Binding Tooltip}" Click="{Binding Click}">
                                  <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="{Binding Icon}"/>
                               </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                         </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                      </ItemsControl>
                   </DockPanel>
                </StackPanel>
             </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Here what I'm doing is creating a ListView and customizing the items inside the ListView. Inside the ListView I have a ItemsControl called ButtonsList, I want to set the ItemsSource parameter of the ItemsControl from the code behind, but I can't get the ButtonsList reference. Is there a way to obtain the reference to ButtonsList from the code behind?

Comment: In the class that contains the ListView items, why don't you create a new list that represents the buttons lists and then bind it to the ItemsControl?

Comment: Because I cant reference the ItemsControl from the code behind. The code behind is where I define the ListView ItemsSource.

Comment: You don't need to reference the ItemsControl from the code behind. You only need to bind the ItemsSource property of it to a List on your class.

Comment: I'm not using MVVM, I'm creating a control and I want to initialize the ItemsControl ItemsSource from the code behind. Maybe I'm not understanding well your suggestion.

Comment: I don't think you can do it an other way. Maybe you should copy the XAML and class of a minimal example here so that we can have more information in order to help you.

Comment: Add loadEvent for each control that you want then in code behind in that event you can get it like this : var yourControl=(yourControlType)sender;